# Is it possible to programmatically set push notification tokens at runtime?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I've set up push notifications in my Android application successfully, using `google-services.json` to specify the various tokens/keys needed. I gather that this file is really a hint for the build process, but the end result is still effectively hard-coded into the app.

I'd like to be able to set those values at runtime, with values coming from a remote server. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think this would be possible using [the builder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions.Builder) and supplying your own values

Comment: So far, this looks like exactly what I needed - thank you!